# Pandas Converting xlsx to CSV - escapechar not working

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to use Pandas to convert my xlsx file to CSV. Some of the data has double quotes and so I am using escape character. However, it doesn't seem to work.

**test.xslx**

[image]

**test.csv** (output)

```
"name"|"address"
"abc"|"""canada"""
"xyz"|"""US"""
```

**expected output**

```
"name"|"address"
"abc"|\""canada"\"
"xyz"|\""US"\"
```

**convert.py**

```py
import csv
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("NLP_data.xlsx")
df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")
df.to_csv("test.csv", sep="|",  index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, encoding="utf-8", escapechar='\\')
```

**What's the purpose of escape character? Shouldn't it escape double quotes as it's part of data ?**

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Which is your current output, and what is your expected output?

Comment: @G.Anderson what's the purpose of escape character. Shouldn't it escape double quotes as it's part of data ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your expected output is correct? I would expect it to look like the following

```
"name","address"
"abc","\"canada\""
"xyz","\"US\""
```

To do that, use the `doublequote = False` parameter

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")
df.to_csv("test.csv",  index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, doublequote = False, encoding="utf-8", escapechar = '\\')
```

If you're sure what you posted as your desired output is really what you need, I'm not sure there's a way to do so.